# xml to java object via JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb

I have the following xml with **measurement** section, I want convert it to java objects. But I have problem with design POJO's object for this section. Can you help me please? Thanks

```xml
<root_element>
   <element>some_value</element>
   <element>some_value</element>     // SOME OTHERS ELEMENT'S
   <element>some_value</element>
   <measurement>                     // BEGINING OF THE SECTION WHERE I HAVE A PROBLEM
       <component>SO2</component>
       <averaged_time>
            <averaged_hours>1</averaged_hours>
            <value>9.054</value>
       </averaged_time>
       <component>NO2</component>
       <averaged_time>
            <averaged_hours>1</averaged_hours>
            <value>14.155</value>
       </averaged_time>
   </measurement>                    // END OF THE SECTION WHERE I HAVE A PROBLEM
   <element>some_value</element>
</root_element>
```

I have something like this (I did not write here other parameters, those work without problem). JAXB return me in Measurement just last one "component" and "averaged_time" elements. I know that `ArrayList <Measurement>` is bad approach.

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class root_element {

      private ArrayList<Measurement> measurements;

      public ArrayList<Measurement> getMeasurements() {
            return measurements;
      }

      @XmlElement (name = "measurement")
      public void setMeasurement(ArrayList<Measurement> measurements) {
            this.measurements = measurements;
      }
}
```

Measurement object

```java
public class Measurement {

    private String component;
    private AveragedTime averagedTime;  

    public String getComponent() {
        return component;
    }

    @XmlElement (name = "component")
    public void setComponent(String component) {
        this.component = component;
    }

    public AveragedTime getAveragedTime() {
        return averagedTime;
    }

    @XmlElement (name = "averaged_time")
    public void setAveragedTime(AveragedTime averagedTime) {
        this.averagedTime = averagedTime;
    }
}
```

AveragedTime object

```
public class AveragedTime {

        private int averaged_hours;
        private double value;

        public int getAveraged_hours() {
            return averaged_hours;
        }

        @XmlElement (name = "averaged_hours")
        public void setAveraged_hours(int averaged_hours) {
            this.averaged_hours = averaged_hours;
        }

        public double getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @XmlElement (name = "value")
        public void setValue(double value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I see with XML, it should be

```
<root_element>
   <element>some_value</element>
   <element>some_value</element>     // SOME OTHERS ELEMENT'S
   <element>some_value</element>
   <measurement>                     // BEGINING OF THE SECTION WHERE I HAVE A PROBLEM
       <component>SO2</component>
       <averaged_time>
            <averaged_hours>1</averaged_hours>
            <value>9.054</value>
       </averaged_time>
   </measurement>
   <measurement>   
       <component>NO2</component>
       <averaged_time>
            <averaged_hours>1</averaged_hours>
            <value>14.155</value>
       </averaged_time>
   </measurement>                    // END OF THE SECTION WHERE I HAVE A PROBLEM
   <element>some_value</element>
</root_element>
```

Rest all your POJO seems fine i.e. in sync as per above suggested xml.

Otherwise if you need to continue with your existing XML, change your classes as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class root_element {

      private Measurement measurements;

     //getter-setters
}
```

Measurement class

```
public class Measurement {

    private List<String> component;
    private List<AveragedTime> averagedTime;  

    //getter-setters

 }
```

Rest all seems ok.

Comment: Yeh, I know, but this is not my xml :( I just need parse it.

Comment: @Samot updated the answer, but if possible change your xml schema as suggested in upper part of answer.

Comment: Thank you, it works. No, unfortunately I can not change the XML schema, because this xml is from Czech Hydrometeorological Institute website, yeah, national institute can't do xml schema correctly.